# database structure for the user hide their personal info

Tags: php, mysql, database

How is the database structure for the user hide their personal info like hp, email address and full name?

Should I create a table (hidden_info) to keep all the private personal info of the users when the users set them to be private through my website.

Then on the user-profile.php page, use mysql to select * on hidden_info_table where user==$username, then use other mysql to select and display the info which are not listed on hidden_info_table?

That will be a lot of works, is there any other better way to construct the database for hiding user personal info feature?

Comment: sounds like a work to be done by app-layer. You can have a user table with full info and display/edit the sensitive data wherever your authorization system allows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a separate table. I would have a settings table separately which would contain that privacy options they have available.

```
Settings

 SettingId int 
 SettingName varchar(100)

UserSettings

 SettingId int
 UserId int
```

Setting's could be ***HideEmail***, ***HideRealName***,  ***HidePhoneNUmber*** for example and you could get the user settings when the user authenticates and store those in session state as an string array (or a custom model)

You could then query the users settings like so:

```
SELECT SettingName
  FROM UserSettings
  LEFT JOIN Settings
  on UserSettings.SettingId = Settings.SettingId
WHERE UserId =1
```

This would return a list of settings for the current user. This should be fairly easy for you to work out the PHP side of things from this.

- Store result in string array
- Check if a ***YourSetting*** is present in the array, if it is don't show that element

Once you have your array just check if a value exists and do your required logic

```
if (!in_array("HideEmail", $results)) {
    echo "Show email address here";
}
```

Comment: let say, there are two records on Settings_table : hideEmail And hidePhone. Let's say userID 18 set private on email and phone both, how is the mysql and php codes to show all the info of 18th user except email and phone?

Comment: see edit. You can have as many settings as you like assigned to the users as you use the UserSettings table to create the relationship with the user.

Comment: $query5 = ("select * from UserSettings where UserId='$userID'"); Then use array to store the result. In this case, the result should be 1 and 2. 1 is the SettingId of hideEmail and 2 is the SettingId of hidePhone. Then use php if (array [0] == 1 and array [1]==2) { ... omg I have no idea how to display all info exclude the private info.

Comment: Look at my query you should avoid using select * you would check if a setting NAME existed in the array it would be more readable that way. You can just use conditional checks around where you display the email for example

Comment: I think you need to run through some examples on php.net if your struggling still at this stage.

Comment: I see. Wow, cool stuff. Thank you. I will try it out now. Thanks for your guidance. I really appreciate it a lot. Thank you.

Comment: May I know why you create a new table (UserSettings) ? Why don't you direct add in a new field (SettingId) on the users table which storing all the info of users?

Comment: Because you would end up with lots of extra fields, one for each setting. Every time you add a new setting you bloat your user table and need to change your DB schema. My solution can be administered by simply adding new entries into the setting and usersetting tables.

Comment: Wow. I see. I never though about that issue before. I understand it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries mate hope you get it all sorted :)

Comment: You shouldn't try to handle the hiding and showing on the client side. Instead, use a view in the database that returns data for columns that aren't hidden, and NULL or "" for data that should be hidden. Revoke permissions on the base tables. Allow client code to read only the view. That way, all future client code will comply with the "hide me" requirements, regardless of how good the client-side programmers are.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column after email called email_hidden

SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE userID = $ID

```
<?php

  if( !$user_info['email_hidden'] ) { echo $user_info['email'] }

?>
```

Duplicate for other fields

This is the simplest method, though not the most efficient.

Comment: Wouldn't recommend this approach although agree it is simple. Again would never use select * in a query of this kind as you would return everything (possibly password any unwanted data)

Comment: is there any way outside people can get the value of php variable if i didn't echo it out?